# How to rotate a line to 90 degree using animation in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have a line drawn over the circle using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer which lies vertically. I want to rotate the line to 90 degree along with animation so that after animation the line lies horizontally.I have tried many animation solutions but the line does not rotates along the circle with same center point and it goes out of the circle. I need to rotate the line with animation without changing the center point.

```
   UIBezierPath *CirclePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(_width*4, _height*4) radius: (_width*3.5)
                          startAngle:0 endAngle: (2*3.14) clockwise:YES]; 
    CAShapeLayer *Circlelayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    Circlelayer.path = [CirclePath CGPath];
    Circlelayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor orangeColor]CGColor];
    Circlelayer.lineWidth = _width*0.6;
    Circlelayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    [self.layer addSublayer:Circlelayer];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(_width*4, _height*0.2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(_width*4, _height*7.8)];

    CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    pathLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    pathLayer.lineWidth = _width*0.8;
    pathLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    [self.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add pathLayer as sublayer to circleLayer, so whenever transformation applied to the circleLayer will also aplied to pathLayer.